# How to get search hits based on one of the attributes in embedded id in hibernate search?

Tags: java, hibernate-search

I have following hibernate search entity class:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class TableA {
    @EmbeddedId
    @DocumentId
    @FieldBridge(impl = TableA_Bridge.class)
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    private TableA_Pk id;
    /*
    Other fields;
    setters and getters;
    */  
}
```

Following is the TableA_Pk class:

```
@Embeddable
public class TableA_Pk implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    /*
    setters and getters;
    */  
}
```

So, now my question is, how do I find hits based on fields, a, b or c in TableA_Pk class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of *TableA_Bridge* should add the fields from each *TableA_Pk* instance to the Lucene Document, with appropriate indexing options, and you can choose which field names you want.

That will make them searchable.

Using the *@FieldBridge* annotation is the "advanced" way to do this, you might want to simply use an *@IndexedEmbedded*, which will automatically add all fields as annotated with *@Field*.
In this case you would not use a *@FieldBridge* annotation.

Comment: I added @IndexedEmbedded above 'id' instance and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.